# SQL Server : concatenate values and ignore null or blank values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, concatenation

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table with a list of addresses, with items in separate columns.

For example:

```
st number Prefix  st name    suffix   Dir    unit    number    city    zip
___________________________________________________________________________
1234       W       Main       St      NULL   Unit     34        LA     90210
345       NULL     George     Ave     NULL   NULL     NULL      SF     94525
123        E       Bloom      Ct       W     NULL     NULL      DC     99342
```

I want to concatenate these addresses and combine them into one single cell.

The main goal is to use that concatenated address to link to another table. for example, if I concatenate using `ISNULL` to ignore the blank values it will give me this

```
345 _ George Ave _ _ _ SF 94525.
```

(I added the `_` to show where a space is used)

It adds a space when there is a null value. If there is a space the link to the other table will not work. I tried `COALESCE` but it didn't work. I am not too familiar with Coalesce, but I think `COALESCE` will give me the first non null value only. what I would like as a result is:

```
1234 W Main St Unit 34 LA 90210
345 George Ave SF 94525
123 E bloom Ct W DC 99342
```

How could I combine these items without spaces in between for the null values? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Post the code you tried already

Comment: `If there is a space the link to the other table will not work.` ... How do plan on joining a partial address with missing information, even if there are no extra spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Prdp's answer, a simple replace (or two) can eliminate the double/triple spaces.

```
Declare @YourTable table ([st number] varchar(25),Prefix varchar(25),[st name] varchar(25),suffix varchar(25),Dir varchar(25),unit varchar(25),number varchar(25),city varchar(25),zip varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('1234','W' ,'Main'  ,'St' ,NULL,'Unit','34','LA','90210'),
('345' ,NULL,'George','Ave',NULL,NULL  ,NULL,'SF','94525'),
('123' ,'E' ,'Bloom' ,'Ct' ,'W' ,NULL  ,NULL,'DC','99342')

Select FullAddress = replace(replace(concat([st number],' ',Prefix,' ',[st name],' ',suffix,' ',Dir,' ',unit,' ',number,' ',city,' ',zip),'   ',' '),'  ',' ')
 From  @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
FullAddress
1234 W Main St Unit 34 LA 90210
345 George Ave SF 94525
123 E Bloom Ct W DC 99342
```

Comment: I understood what Gordan was saying about my answer after looking at your answer

Comment: @Prdp I lean towards the concat approach.  I have no idea if it is faster, but in my little head, it looks cleaner.

Comment: Most importantly it does implicit conversion I like that. I missed that replace part :/. As far as I have used there is no performance issue with `CONCAT` function like `FORMAT` ;)

Comment: This may happen to work on the data, but it is rather difficult to formulate when you have arbitrary numbers of adjacent `NULL` columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if I understand your comment.  It would take 6 consecutive nulls to be an issue.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @Prdp , your solution was great. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select (coalesce(st_number + ' ', '') +
        coalesce(prefix + ' ', '') +
        coalesce(st_name + ' ', '') +
        . . .
       )
```

That leaves a remaining space at the end of the string.  You can remove it using `rtrim()`.

```
select rtrim(coalesce(st_number + ' ', '') +
             coalesce(prefix + ' ', '') +
             coalesce(st_name + ' ', '') +
             . . .
            )
```

As Prdp points out, this assumes that the columns are actually strings.  Otherwise, explicit conversion will be needed for those columns (or you can use the `concat()` function instead of `+`).

Comment: You should comment that, e.g., `st_number + ' '` is `NULL` if the column itself is `NULL`.

Comment: Also this considers columns are implicitly convertible to datatype with highest precedence. When the datatype is of `numeric` then empty string and space in `Coalesce` will be converted to `0`